# What happens if arguments passed to sscanf are cast

Tags: c, casting, scanf

While reviewing and old piece of code, I stumbled upon some coding horror like this one:

```
struct Foo
{
    unsigned int  bar;
    unsigned char qux;
    unsigned char xyz;
    unsigned int  etc;
};

void horror(const char* s1, const char* s2, const char* s3, const char* s4, Foo* foo)
{
    sscanf(s1, "%u", &(foo->bar));
    sscanf(s2, "%u", (unsigned int*) &(foo->qux));
    sscanf(s3, "%u", (unsigned int*) &(foo->xyz));
    sscanf(s4, "%u", &(foo->etc));
}
```

So, what is actually happening in the second and third `sscanf`, with the argument passed being a `unsigned char*` cast to `unsigned int*`, but with the format specifier for an unsigned integer? Whatever happens is due to undefined behavior, but why is this even "working"?

As far as I know, the cast effectively does nothing in this case (the actual type of the arguments passed as `...` is unknown to the called function). However this has been in production for years and it has never crashed and the surrounding values apparently are not overwritten, I suppose because the members of the structure are all aligned to 32 bits. This is even reading the correct value on the target machine (a little endian 32 bit ARM) but I think that it would no longer work on a different endianness.

Bonus question: what is the cleanest correct way to do this? I know that now we have the `%hhu` format specifier (apparently introduced by C++11), but what about a legacy C89 compiler?

---

Please note that the original question had `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned int` and `unsigned char` instead of `uint8_t` but that was just misleading and out of topic, and by the way the original code I was reviewing uses its own typedefs.

Comment: Is `xyz` really aligned to 32bits? Otherwise `sscanf(s3, "%u", (uint32_t*) &(foo->xyz));` will have an analigned write access.

Comment: @mch: you are right, `sizeof(Foo)` is 12

Comment: @Broman: of course it is undefined behavior, the question is: what is actually happening? Why does this still work on this architecture?

Comment: As to why it happens to work regardless of alignment: [Apparently some ARM cores do support some unaligned accesses.](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473m/dom1359731171041.html)

Comment: You could run into problems with endianness and alignment on some platforms.  Others will appear to work.  None of them is guaranteed to work.  One solution is to read the values into a local `unsigned int` variable and assign the value scanned to the member of the structure, possibly after range-checking the values destined for the `uint8_t` variables (and preferably after checking the result from `sscanf()` each time and dealing with any failures).

Comment: "but what about a legacy C89 compiler?" --> C89 does not have ` uint8_t,  uint32_t`, so scanning is just one of many problems then.

Comment: @chux that was obviously not the point of the question. Anyway, I replaced the fixed integer types from C99 with the plain old types.

Comment: Poor SO etiquette to fundamental change the question as answer come in.  Rolled back.

Comment: @chux: that was a perfectly legitimate edit on a minor detail. I will redo the edit.

Comment: If you feel the edit was minor, it can go either way - including leaving it as original.  Yet 3 answers all are reduced in value as they all address the original fixed width types.

Comment: @chux please note that your own answer is OT in either case: the question is clearly "what kind of undefined behavior is causing this obvious bug to work"; you answered "code is UB as scan specifiers does not match arguments".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this of course invokes Undefined Behaviour.

But that kind of horror was quite common in old code, where the C language was used as a higher level assembly language. So here are 2 possible behaviours:

- the structure has a 32 bits alignment. All is (rather fine) on a little endian machine: the `uint8_t` members will recieve the least significant byte of the 32 bits value and the padding bytes will be zeroed (I assume that the program does not try to store a value greater than 255 into an `uint8_t`)
- the structure has not a 32 bits alignement, but the architecture allows `scanf` to write into mis-aligned variables. The least significant byte of the value read for `qux` will correctly go into `qux` and the next 3 zero bytes will erase `xyz` and `etc`. On next line, `xyz` receives its value and `etc` recieves one more 0 byte. And finally `etc` will recieve its value. This could have been a rather common hack in the early 80' on an 8086 type machine.

For a portable way, I would use an temporary unsigned integer:

```
uint32_t u;
sscanf(s1, "%u", &(foo->bar));
sscanf(s2, "%u", &u);
foo->qux = (uint8_t) u;
sscanf(s3, "%u", &u);
foo->xyz = (uint8_t) u;
sscanf(s4, "%u", &(foo->etc));
```

and trust the compiler to generate code as efficient as the *horror* way.

Comment: `uint32_t u;` `sscanf(s2, "%u", &u);` make sense when `unsigned` is  32-bit.  Yet C does not require that.

Answer (score 3):

> Bonus question: what is the cleanest correct way to do this? I know that now we have the %hhu format specifier (apparently introduced by C++11), but what about a legacy C89 compiler?

The `<stdint.h>` header and its types were introduced in C99, so a C89 compiler won't support them except as an extension.

The correct way to use the `*scanf()` and `*printf()` families of functions with the various fixed or minimum-width types is to use the macros from [`<inttypes.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer). For example:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int8_t foo;
  uint_least16_t bar;

  puts("Enter two numbers");
  if (scanf("%" SCNd8 " %" SCNuLEAST16, &foo, &bar) != 2) {
    fputs("Input failed!\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  printf("You entered %" PRId8 " and %" PRIuLEAST16 "\n", foo, bar);
}
```

Comment: As an additional note for C89: just use temporary variable with correct type. Or simply use `strtoul` as there seems to be no benefit in using `sscanf`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case from the pointer point of view nothing as on the all modern machines pointers are the same for all types.

But because you use wrong formats - the scanf will write outside the memory allocated to the variables and it is an Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: *the scanf will write outside the memory allocated* Unless the hardware has alignment restrictions on 32-bit `int` values that don't exist for `char` values, and the original `char` value isn't properly aligned.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Even if there is a padding (and this the implementation related thing) it is still the UB. Just imagine the build where structs are packed.

Answer (score 0):

OP code is UB as scan specifiers does not match arguments.

> cleanest correct way to do this?

**Cleaner**

```
#include <inttypes.h>

void horror1(const char* s1, const char* s2, const char* s3, const char* s4, Foo* foo) {
    sscanf(s1, "%" SCNu32, &(foo->bar));
    sscanf(s2, "%" SCNu8, &(foo->qux));
    sscanf(s2, "%" SCNu8, &(foo->xyz));
    sscanf(s1, "%" SCNu32, &(foo->etc));
}
```

**Cleanest**

Add additional error handling if desired.

```
void horror2(const char* s1, const char* s2, const char* s3, const char* s4, Foo* foo) {
    foo->bar = (uint32_t) strtoul(s1, 0, 10);
    foo->qux = (uint8_t) strtoul(s1, 0, 10);
    foo->xyz = (uint8_t) strtoul(s1, 0, 10);
    foo->etc = (uint32_t) strtoul(s1, 0, 10);
}
```